# Swagger/Swashbuckle: Ignore overloaded endpoint in base class

Tags: .net, api, swagger, overloading, swashbuckle

So I have a base controller class with a *search(string query)* method, with the path */search*. And I have a child class with *search(string query, string name)*, also with path */search*.

The Swagger API generated by Swashbuckle contains both endpoints, and they have a conflict error. Now what I want is to ignore the parent class' search method, but only for the child that has a *search()* overload. (Since parameters are optional, the parent's search method would conforms to the child's anyway.)

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `[NonAction]` attribute to parent's search method or make it protected